# Authentication on Android

Tags: java, android, openid, oauth, authorization

Hi I am developing an Android App where I require a user to authenticate his session before using the app. One way is to store a user name and password by asking him to register on the app and then use that to authenticate him. But i was looking to do something else, maybe use an OpenId account to authenticate or Opensoial or something like Facebook Connect. Any Suggestions and comments? thanks for you help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, please do not whine about not getting answers after only an hour, particularly when it's Sunday in much of the world. If you want responses in less than an hour on a weekend, hire an expensive consultant.

> Hi I am developing an Android App
>   where I require a user to authenticate
>   his session before using the app.

Why?

> Any Suggestions and comments?

Most Android applications do not require authentication for local use. They may require authentication for access to online content (e.g., Web service), in which case the authentication is handled by the Web service and uses technology dictated by the Web service.

Bear in mind that any online authentication process (e.g., OAuth, Facebook Connect) means your application cannot be used in offline mode.

If your goal is to use authentication as some means of helping to combat piracy, you might consider using the new [LVL system](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2010/07/licensing-service-for-android.html) that Google released this week.